# Object detection on raspberry pi

Tags: tensorflow, github, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to run the following project:

https://github.com/krishrustagi/Accident-Detection-System

I do not know what I am doing wrong.This project seems really interesting and I really want to learn more about it.

How do I get the github repository above to work.
Maybe a simple fix?

Here is the error code I get when executing the camera.py command:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/Project/Accident-Detection-System $ python3 camera.py    Traceback 
(most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Project/Accident-Detection-System/camera.py", line 6, in <module>
model = AccidentDetectionModel("model.json", 'model_weights.h5')
File "/home/pi/Project/Accident-Detection-System/detection.py", line 15, in __init__
self.loaded_model.load_weights(model_weights_file)
File "/home/pi/Project/Accident-Detection-System/env/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/pi/Project/Accident-Detection-System/env/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 533, in __init__
fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
File "/home/pi/Project/Accident-Detection-System/env/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 226, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 
'model_weights.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags 
= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error trace is telling you that the file `model_weights.h5` does not exist anywhere in the project root directory.

After looking at the GitHub repo, it seems that `model.json` exists but `model_weights.h5` does not, while both are supplied as arguments in `camera.py` Line 6:

`model = AccidentDetectionModel("model.json", 'model_weights.h5')`

The README mentioned this in Section 5:

> `accident-classification.ipynb`: This is a jupyter notebook that generates a model to classify the above data. This file generates two important files `model.json` and `model_weights.h5`.

Hence you should run `accident-classification.ipynb` first before running `camera.py`.

Comment: Running that trains the model which takes hours.

Comment: Try using `epoch=1` (originally 20 epochs). Else, contact the author (file an issue)  to provide the `model_weights.h5` file.

Comment: When running the ipynb file to get the h5 file I get the following error: allocation of XXX exceeds 10% of system memory. So I reduced batch size to 2 and I also  tried 32. I trained the model with both those batch sizes values to see if it would run better. I don't know how batch size effects the model. Anyway, decreasing the batch size seems to make the memory issue go away and I am able to get the h5 file and run the camera detector. However, it always says "accident" with some percentage. So it is not functioning as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is probably due to your RAM. Reducing batch size helps because it reduces your RAM memory utilization. It only affects the model training time, not model accuracy.
On the "it always says "accident" with some percentage", it means that the model thinks its an accident (even it shouldn't) - that is an example of low model accuracy. Did you reduced the batch size only or the epochs as well?